# Can you still publish app written in Swift 3 on app store with Xcode 10.1?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store

Developer.apple.com says swift 4 can be publishable but nothing about swift3 also says xcode 10.1 requires but if I use swift 3 with xcode 10.1 can I publish my app on appStore, or I need to update to swift 4-5 ? I can not find any resource for my question.

Developer before me, published this app on 25 March 2019 with swift 3. At that time swift 5 pusblished. Is this change something ?

Comment: I think this link will be enough to prove that swift 3 still can publisable. Thank you. If you want you can answer the question and I can marked to resolved.

Comment: I’ll delete the comment then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple only has requirement for Xcode version, so as long as your app is built with Xcode version supported by `App Store Connect`([reference](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb1c185036)), you will be fine.

Though from Xcode's [Release Note](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes) :

> Xcode 10 is the last release that will support Swift 3.

Swift 3 will not be supported in future version of Xcode, when it happens, you will have to update to swift 4/5.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can if you're using Xcode 10.1